# Angular directive shading table cells based on value

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table, css-tables

I have an `M x N` table of data. Each row contains data for one student. Each column is his/her performance in a course compared to the class average, i.e., the % difference between his/her grade and the average.

```
cellValue = (studentGrade - avgGrade)/avgGrade * 100
```

I want to color each cell based on this `cellValue`. If the % difference is higher, the cell should be green, and the higher the grade, the darker the green. If the % difference is lower, the cell should be red, and the lower the grade, the darker the red.

Is there an Angular directive that allows me to do something like this?

Comment: Share your code..

Comment: Don't have any yet. Just have the JSON code. I'm looking for a "heatmap" directive sort of thing.